# How do i get the full response headers using restsharp?

Tags: c#, python-requests, restsharp

im using restsharp to send requests to https://httpbin.org/post but the only thing i get back is `StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers: { }`  how do i get the headers?

my code:

```
  var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.mail.tm/accounts")
            {
                Proxy = GetWebProxy(),
                ThrowOnAnyError = true,
                Timeout = 10000
            };
            var client = new RestClient(options);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            var body = new post { address = name + number +"@cutradition.com", password = "password" };
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
           var response = await client.PostAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(request);

           Console.WriteLine(response);

       Console.WriteLine(response);
```

if you know how to get the headers please tell me

Answer (score 0):

`PostAsync<HttpResponseMessage>` makes no sense as RestSharp will try to deserialize the response to `HttpRequestMessage`, and it is not something I would expect from your server.

I strongly suggest reading the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#making-a-call).

If you change your code to this:

```
var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
```

you will get all the headers and the response content inside the `response` object.